# How to make JavaScript run for only a portion of DOM

Tags: javascript

I am adding features to a project and I have to import a different version of jQuery because the plugin needs a different version, but the project also has a plugin that depends on the version of jQuery already being used.

To achieve this, is there a way to make a particular JS run only for a section and then get destroyed?

eg

```html
<section id="sec1"></section>
<section id="sec2"></section>
```

and the script

```html
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

I want `main.js` to be loaded only on `#sec1` and destroyed afterwards.

Comment: Can you expand a little more on what the script is supposed to do? If you are just attaching certain listeners, adding an ID to the container element (and respective selectors) might be enough.

Comment: Scripts can remove themselves from the DOM using `document.currentScript.remove();`. But what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I think you could accomplish something like this would be using the Web Component spec. Web Components (specifically the Shadow DOM) are isolated from the main `document` object. You can use functions inside the component without polluting the global scope.

You can read more about them here :

[Web Components](https://css-tricks.com/an-introduction-to-web-components/)

Comment: Good point. Wouldn't the Shadow DOM by itself already be enough? What would you need the other parts of the Web Components spec for?

Comment: For some reason when I wrote it I had a reason to include but I cannot remember why. If I don't remember what the point was I'll edit. Thanks!